# Dedicated Server won't reach login

Tags: boot, systemd-journald

My server is scheduled to restart every Sunday morning at ~1AM. This week, it never came back up after the restart. Whether I attempt to boot into live mode or recovery mode, it stops at the same point and will not go to a command line or console. I've tried searching around and every reference I can find to the WATCHDOG=1 notification message is when the machine is powering down however this is happening while it's powering up.

Any help would be appreciated!

Console log:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being bad sectors on the HDD. Drive was dead.